# Cannot await 'System.collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api

I'm using Entity Framework 6.1 within a WEB API project and am simply trying to pass a collection back but am getting the above subject line error.

In addition, there is no **ToListAsync**() method available in the intellisense.

The design time compile error is immediately over the await statement.

**How can I correct the above subject error and also have the ToListAsync method available?**

Here are my code snippets:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<HH_FuelTkt_Output>> GetFilteredFuelTicketsAsync(HH_FuelTkt_Input value)

List<HH_FuelTkt_Output> tkts = await DbContext.HH_FuelTkt.Select(s =>
                            new
                            {
                                s.Customer_Name,
                                s.FuelTkt_ID,
                                s.Image_ID,
                                s.Ticket_No,
                                s.Trans_Timestamp,
                                s.Vehicle_No
                            }
                            ).ToList();
```

Comment: Is the framework set to 4.5?

Comment: You should probably research enough about async/await so that you can at least understand why awaiting a list does not make sense.

Comment: Just return a task and do not await (because you're not using any Async function)? You won't make ToList() asynchronous but you'll make your method so.

Comment: `ToListAsync()` is defined in [`System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn220262(v=vs.113).aspx). Are you missing a `using System.Data.Entity;` directive? But even if you add that, it won't compile, your list is of the wrong type.

Comment: @usr Why doesn't it make sense? Where is the list?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen `await x.ToList()` never makes sense. `await x.ToListAsync()` can make sense, which is what the OP wants to do, but the OP also asks why `await x.ToList()` gives an error.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen he's awaiting the result of a call to ToList which returns a `List<T>`. You wouldn't say `await new List<int>()`, would you?

Comment: ZoolWay, framework is 4.5.1

Comment: He's primarily asking why `ToListAsync` is not available, which *does* make sense, to await that.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I understand that. I try to help him by alerting him to the fact that he's using a technology (await) without understanding the basics. That's dangerous.

Comment: hvd, adding the System.Data.Entity namespace gave me the ToListAsync(). Thanks

Comment: I changed the List<HH_FuelTkt_Output> to var and it worked! Thanks everybody for their help :)

Comment: usr, I know enough about asynchronous programming to get by. hvd, thanks so much for your help.

Comment: hvd, one more question... When I try and do the following "return tkts;", I get the design time compile error of "Cannot implicitly convert type Generic List to HH_FuelTkt_Output" which is my output type. How can I convert the anonymous type to my output type?

Answer (score 1):

There is **ToListAsync** [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn220262(v=vs.113).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn220262%28v=vs.113%29.aspx)

**Namespace**:  System.Data.Entity

**Assembly**:  EntityFramework (in EntityFramework.dll)

Do you have using for System.Data.Entity? ToListAsync is an extension method.

Comment: Added that and worked. However, when I try and do the following "return tkts;", I get the design time compile error of "Cannot implicitly convert type Generic List to HH_FuelTkt_Output" which is my output type. How can I convert the anonymous type to my output type?

Comment: Figured it out... Added a type initializer after the "new" statement, then assigned the properties inside the type initializer to the "s." fields.